# sudo dpkg --configure -a

Tags: dpkg, sudo, configure

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

On typing this command I am not able to resolve the problem

```
dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a
```

and the terminal window gets hanged.
On <kbd>CLTR</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> it says `[2]+ stopped`

Comment: Did you tried "sudo apt install -f"? What it gives to you?