# sudo dpkg --configure -a Taking forever

Tags: apt, php, php-fpm

I am trying to install php-fpm with `sudo apt-get install php-fpm`. When I do that commmand, it gives the error: `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

When I type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` it says:
`Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (1:10.1.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...`, and takes forever. I have tried rebooting, but that does not do much.

I need to install php-fpm (and others), so i'm not really sure what to.

I have read these posts: and did what they all say, to no avail

[sudo dpkg --configure -a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951805/sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

[sudo dpkg --configure -a takes forever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968465/sudo-dpkg-configure-a-takes-forever)

[sudo dpkg --configure -a error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175903/sudo-dpkg-configure-a-error)

Comment: Have you tried strace? `sudo strace sudo dpkg --configure -a`  ... The solution could also be found with unpack the .deb archive, read the install script and do it step by step ... But strace will tell us where to search ... In your case I assume the script wants to stop the service ant maybe it is already stopped? Or the Service wait for the service to stop/halt and in the mariadb log are more information why it can't? ... But first we need the place where is waiting and for what.

Comment: I ended up reseting the server, but thank you. If this happens again, I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Remove Mariadb or Uninstall Mariadb
4. Install Mariadb

This way I solved My Problem.